# First time dealing with limits with complex numbers in it.

Tags: analysis, complex-numbers

I am solving the following problem.

> Investigate the behavior (convergence of divergence) of $\Sigma a_n$ if
>
> $$a_n = \frac{1}{1+z^n}, \quad \text{ for } z \in \Bbb C.$$

First of all, I am not quite sure what it means when $\lim_{n \to \infty} z^n$ .

I am thinking if $|z| < 1$ it goes to 0, but from my understanding, multiplying complex numbers is like multiplying the magnitude of the vectors and adding the angles of the vectors. So I am imagining a hand of a clock increasing its length and rotating over an over... to something analogous to $\infty$.

Second, I tried to algebraically deal with this if I could get anywhere with the ratio test. And I got

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} |\frac{1+z^n}{1+z^{n+1}}| = \lim_{n \to \infty} |{1 \over z}| $$

and it will converge when

$$|{1 \over z}| \lt 1.$$

Putting $z = a + bi$, I found that

$$\sqrt{1 \over {a^2+b^2}} \lt 1$$

is the necessary condition for the series to converge.

Despite not knowing what it means, I got something. Am I on the right track ? Or am I dating myself here?

Comment: The Ratio Test works well here, so you are definitely on the right track. The only thing that will be left undecided by the Ratio Test is the behaviour of the circle $|z|=1$. You need to deal with that separately.

Comment: If $|z| < 1$ then you won't be increasing the length - rather decreasing. The intuition here becomes that it tends to $0$, which is correct.

Comment: $\left|\frac{1}{z}\right|<1\implies |z|>1$. This is a condition that guarantees convergence by the Ratio Test, while $|z|<1$ implies divergence. For $|z|=1$, the terms are not approaching $0$, so the series would diverge there as well.

Comment: @AndréNicolas: Letting |z| = 1, I see that it diverges when z $\in \Bbb R$ but what happens if it is complex ? What does it mean for a complex number to diverge ?

Comment: A sequence of complex numbers diverges if it does not converge. In our case, it is enough to show that if $|x|=1$ and $z\ne 1$, then the sequence $(z^n)$ does not converge. If it converged to $Z_0$, we would have $zz_0=z_0$. But $z_0$ cannot be $0$, since all the $z^n$ have norm $1$.

Comment: Ahh, that makes sense. Thanks !